# Execute AsyncTask in a headless Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-asynctask

I have read that executing `AsyncTask` in an `Activity` has the disadvantage that the task does not cope well with configuration changes, since the `AsyncTask`'s lifecycle is not tied on the `Activity` lifecycle. Consequently, if the task should update the UI of an Activity but in the meantime the `Activity` has been destroyed due to a configuration change, the `AsyncTask` does not know anything of the newly created `Activity` and therefore it has no chance to update it. That can lead to memory leak as well.

The workaround proposed it to use an headless `Fragment` (`Fragment` with no UI), just to execute the `AsyncTask`, because it can survive configuration changes. I do not comprehend though, how it could be a viable approach, since the `Activity` and its views have been destroyed in any case. Example:

```
  public MyFragment extends Fragment {
        private SomeAsync myAsync = new SomeAsync();
        private WeakReference<View> someActivityView;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true);
        }

        public void setActivityView(View View) {
            someActivityView = new WeakReference<View>(view);
        } 

        ...

        class SomeAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Object> {

        protected Object doInBackground(Void... args) {
         ...
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
             doUpdate(someActivityView, result);
         }

         }
       }
```

The `someActivityView` is a `View` which belongs to the `Activity` and it is set to the `Fragment` to be updated. 
I think the `someActivityView` is not preserved in case of a configuration change while the `Activity` is created again, hence what is the benefit of using a headless `Fragment` in this case?

Comment: You should not be updating the activity view directly. Create a callback and  implement it in activity. Now in fragment use getActivity() and cast that to callback and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, what you read about AsyncTask is true, yes viewLess fragment is a way around it.

the general idea on doing something with the fragment is that it has access to whichever activity is the current active activity. That way, instead of storing the actual view using `public void setActivityView(View View) {` you should only store the **id** of this view and find it in the activity whenever you need it.

I'll copy your code and change a few things on it to show the result. But there're other ways of doing it. I'll briefly talk about them at the end.

```
  public MyFragment extends Fragment {
        private SomeAsync myAsync = new SomeAsync();
        private int viewId = -1;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setRetainInstance(true);

            // restore the view id
            if(savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey("myViewId")){
                  viewId = savedInstanceState.getInt("myViewId");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
             super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
             // save the view ID
             if(viewId > 0) {
                outState.putInt("myViewId", viewId);
             }
        }

        public void setActivityView(View View) {
            viewId = view.getId();
        } 

        ...

        class SomeAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Object> {

        protected Object doInBackground(Void... args) {
         ...
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
             Activity activity = getActivity();
             if(viewId > 0 && activity != null) {
                 View view = activity.findViewById(viewId);
                 doUpdate(view, result);
             }
         }

         }
       }
```

And yes, it's necessary to save the ID because there're other reasons your activity might be killed (e.g. goes to background and system runs out of memory);

**Alternatives:**

1. put the view ID directly into the fragment `setArguments(bundle)`.
2. Make the activity implement an interface with method that receives your `AsyncTask`. Then `onPostExecute` you call `getActivity`, cast to this interface and pass the result directly to the activity.
3. (that alternative is my favorite because it's the cleanest): Do not use AsyncTask and do not tie together processing result with UI components. Create a proper structure with data, processing and UI separation. UI elements should only be updated based on subscriptions to data elements. There're several patterns that can help with separation of responsabilitites. MVP, MVC, MVVM, etc. Pick one.

Comment: One of the two first options is essential if I use AsyncTask. I do not consider the third option as a whole solution to my question. Even if the views are managed by a separete class, a callback should be implemented to notify it.